# What is the order of data comparison in the database for SELECT by column A OR column B

Tags: mysql, sql, select, comparison

I have a query where I need to fetch a row by 1) comparing by old_email, and if not found then 2) by comparing the email column. 
I need to make sure that the **first check** is always by an **old** email, and the **second check** is by the **new** email if the old one wasn't found.

I know that I **can't** use **set** because the comparison order is not guaranteed, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE (email IN ('old@example.com', 'new@example.com'))
```

Will the following code satisfy my needs:

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE (email = 'old@example.com' OR email = 'new@example.com')
```

Comment: Why would the comparision order matter if you want rows where the email is either the old one or the new one? Both queries should work just fine.

Comment: How are you going to distinguish whether the eMail ID is old or new(updated) if both of them are under the same column?

Comment: @slaasko The order the OP refers to is the row order *(not the order of evaluation of the predicate's parts)*.  Because the OP only wants to search for the second email address if no records are found for the first email address.  *(In other words, the OP is currently unsure how to word such a requirement in SQL.)*

Comment: @slaakso: the same user has registered twice, first time with a user+test@example.com and the second time with user@example.com. For my specific case I want to ensure that the initial case is always satisfied.

Comment: Neither query achieves your ambition. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @YusufHassan the same user has two different IDs in the users table, so the column name is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `WHERE` clause is applied ***row by row***.  The result from one row is unaware of the result from another row.

What you seems to be describing is "look for email address X, if not found look for email address Y".

There are a few ways to do that.  The following, for example, is a very literal approach to what you described...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  champions
WHERE
  email = 'new@example.com'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  *
FROM
  champions
WHERE
  email = 'old@example.com'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM champions WHERE email = 'new@example.com')
```

That does literally what you described.  Find email address X.  Also find email address Y, on the condition that email address X is not present.

That's pretty verbose though, you end up checking for `'X'` twice...  It's better to think in a more set based manner.

1. Find records with email addresses X or Y
2. Sort them so that records with email address X come first
3. Pick only the first record

For example...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  champions
WHERE
  email IN ('old@example.com', 'new@example.com')
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN email = 'new@example.com' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
LIMIT
  1
```

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie, exactly.